# In CSS is there any need for backup fonts when applying custom fonts to a webpage?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

In CSS why is a backup font recommended if I am uploading a custom font for use with the webpage?

I thought the backup fonts were only needed in case the client doesn't have the 1st/2nd/3rd..etc choice installed.

For example if you have this code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    src: url('../fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf');
}
```

Why is this necessary?

```css
body {
    font-family: MyCustomFont, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not *necessary* to specify a font stack, but it helps to degrade gracefully in obscure cases when a browser is unable to use the font somehow, e.g. if the HTTP request for the font file times out, the font file itself becomes corrupted or otherwise unusable, the browser doesn't support any of the given font formats, among others.

You should do your best to ensure the custom font gets downloaded and used properly, of course. But things can and do happen that are out of your control sometimes, so it doesn't hurt to still have something nice to fall back to. That's why they're called backup or fallback fonts :)

Comment: In addition, browser settings may disable the use of downloadable fonts, even though such settings might be relatively well hidden. On the other hand, some browser add-ons (like NoScript) may do such things without even letting the user know.

Comment: @Jukka: As a daily NoScript user who encounters that frequently, I'm surprised that didn't occur to me as I was writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

DaveRandom, these would be the only nested while loops involved in the business of computing.

I figured out a way to integrate Google Fonts without any of the problems usually found when 3rd party fonts are used.

First off, we know our Google Fonts files are in the .woff format and may not work in all browsers.

Second, if a Google Cloud or some other molest prevents the download of the font file from our server due to cache restrictions or other network limits we know this pseudo-state of connectivity will likely support the .woff fonts from Google Fonts.

To the credit of Google we may be able to load our images in some other way so why not try a Google Fonts version of our end product.. so here is why not:

*In order to insure the font remains the same when adding Google Fonts I recommend not removing the self-hosted fonts unless a verified plaintiff requests you do so for rights ownership reasons.*

Instead of removing self-hosted fonts which are the true key to real cross-browser compatibility, create a same-font entry in CSS that specifies it's font title as 3rd party such as: 'ArialVanityGoogleFonts'.
Use the browser's built-in font fallback .csv and include the fonts as follows: ArialVanity, ArialVanityGoogleFonts, Arial

Comment: What does "Google Cloud or some other molest prevents the download..." mean?